# Generating multiple equally sized output files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, data-partitioning, hadoop-partitioning

What are some methods for finding X data ranges in Hadoop so that one can use these ranges as partitions in the reducer step?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like [TotalOrderPartitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/TotalOrderPartitioner.html), which allows a total order by reading split points from an externally generated source. You might find this link useful :
http://chasebradford.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/reusable-total-order-sorting-in-hadoop/.

Don't know if this is exactly what you need? Apologies if I have get it wrong.